# Disable lock screen wallpaper on S3 Android 4.3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean, wallpaper

I can change the wallpaper on the lock screen on my S3, but is it possible disable it completely? I can't see that in the menus, I am only able to pick a wallpaper from the gallery.

Comment: You want to remove the wallpaper? Or you have set a wallpaper, and you don't want it to be editable / changeable?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove it.

Comment: Why don't you just change it to a black wallpaper?

Comment: That was my first idea as well. What I really want to achieve is to try if the screen comes on faster after the power switch is pressed when no wallpaper is configured.  But looks like this (no wallpaper configured) can't be achieved.

Comment: There's a `No Wallpaper` app on Google Play, which you install as a live wallpaper. Doesn't take a lot of resources. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. Looks like you can't set a live wallpaper for the lock screen, only for both lock screen and normal screen (not sure what it's called). Having said that, I tried to set it for both and the speed of screen power on did not change.  But thank you for your effort. Looks like it can't be achieved, so if you answer the question I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and change it to a black wallpaper. There is a [No Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.wallpaper&hl=en) app on Google Play, which you install as a live wallpaper. It doesn't take a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have root access, then this is how you do it.

1. Navigate to `/data/system/users/0/`
2. Here you will find the file `keyguard_wallpaper`

Deleting it will set your lockscreen wallpaper to reflect your main wallpaper.

Answer (score -1):

Install a pitch black wallpaper on your phone.  Search it in Google Play Store and install the app.  Then you can go to your phone's settings, device, screen, wallpapers, choose lock and home screen, then choose live wallpapers and you will be able to display the "no wallpaper app".

If you choose just the lockscreen, you wont see the application but you can only choose from the gallery.

This is what I did on my Note 2.